# BIGQUERY / my queries are very slow and expensive

Tags: json, optimization, google-bigquery

I have a database in Firestore, send the information to Bigquery with a extension 'Stream Collections to BigQuery'.

But I have the tables with all the data in the same column called 'data'. Also, the data shows all the records/logs, and I just want to see the latest status.

To be able to see the data separated by columns and see the last value, create this query and them save as view.

```
SELECT
  document_name,
  document_id,
  timestamp,
  event_id,
  operation,
  created_at, 
  status_old, 
  status_new
 

FROM
  (
    SELECT
      document_name,
      document_id,
      FIRST_VALUE(timestamp) OVER(
        PARTITION BY document_name
        ORDER BY
          timestamp DESC
      ) AS timestamp,
      FIRST_VALUE(event_id) OVER(
        PARTITION BY document_name
        ORDER BY
          timestamp DESC
      ) AS event_id,
      FIRST_VALUE(operation) OVER(
        PARTITION BY document_name
        ORDER BY
          timestamp DESC
      ) AS operation,
   FIRST_VALUE(`proyect_name.DatasetID.firestoreTimestamp`(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.timestamp'))) OVER(
        PARTITION BY document_name
        ORDER BY
          timestamp DESC
      ) AS created_at,
         FIRST_VALUE(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.metadata.old')) OVER(
        PARTITION BY document_name
        ORDER BY
          timestamp DESC
      ) AS status_old,
              FIRST_VALUE(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.metadata.new')) OVER(
        PARTITION BY document_name
        ORDER BY
          timestamp DESC
      ) AS status_new

    FROM
      table1
    ORDER BY
      document_name,
      timestamp DESC
  )
GROUP BY
  document_name,
  document_id,
  timestamp,
  event_id,
  operation,
  created_at, 
  status_old, 
  status_new
```

(I have several fields to add in addition to these, but it is just an example).

For all my querys, I use to use this 'view'.

The problem I have is that this query /view, takes a long time and cost:

- Bytes processed: 555.78 MB
- Bytes billed: 556 MB
- Elapsed time: 43 sec
- Slot time consumed: 4 min 29 sec
- Bytes shuffled: 836.62 MB

Is there a way to make this more optimal?

Answer (score 0):

Hope these are helpful:

1. Remove `ORDER BY` in your subquery first. It will slow down your query and doesn't make any difference to the result.
2. It seems all the `FIRST_VALUE` come from same row. If so, you can simplify your query like this.

```sql
SELECT document_name,
       document_id,
       first_values.*
FROM (
  SELECT document_name,
         document_id,
         FIRST_VALUE(STRUCT(
           timestamp,
           event_id,
           operation,
           `proyect_name.DatasetID.firestoreTimestamp`(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.timestamp')) AS created_at,
           JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.metadata.old') AS status_old,
           JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(data, '$.metadata.new') AS status_new
          ) OVER (PARTITION BY document_name ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS first_values
     FROM table1
)
```

3. Lastly, you seems to try to remove duplicates with `GROUP BY` in your outer(main) query.
   But I don't think your inner query make duplicates. So, check if your subquery makes duplicates first and if not, remove `GROUP BY` from the outer query.